# Consumir WebService PHP/SOAP no Android

Tags: android, web-service, soap, ksoap2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android que consome um webservice PHP através da biblioteca ksoap2.

Atualmente estou consultando o webservice com uma classe que estende uma AsyncTask. Só que por ela fazer a tarefa em paralelo com a UI Thread estou tendo problemas na lógica do programa.

Será que eu posso fazer as requisições ao webservice em uma classe normal que não estenda uma AsyncTask?

---

O problema era que eu estava comparando os dados de login do meu objeto usuário enquanto da AsyncTask ainda estava atualizando esses dados. Com isso o usuário não conseguia logar ao inserir seus dados. A solução foi fazer a comparação no onPostExcute() da AsyncTask, bem simples. Obrigado pela contribuição de todos e realmente é bem melhor realizar tarefas pesadas em uma thread separada.

Comment: Nos explique o problema que você está tendo ao executar em uma *thread* separada que talvez seja mais fácil darmos uma sugestão.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema vou colocar uma resposta explicando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não deve fazer isso. É preciso usar uma thread separada para lidar com rede. Para requisições HTTP você pode usar as bibliotecas OkHttp/Retrofit ou Volley, se não se sentir a vontade implementando a AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Se você executar a requisição na UI Thread sua aplicação (i.e. vulgo tela) ficaram travadas até a consulta retornar do servidor. Isso não é uma boa prática deixando a usabilidade do seu aplicativo abaixo do esperado!

Recomendo você analisar a questão de concorrência do seu app ao invés de partir para a UI Thread. Não seja um crente da "religião" Extreme Go Horse - http://www.carlostristacci.com.br/blog/extreme-go-horse-xgh/

Espero ter ajudado!